# access/set object's values by indexing it by property name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object called caser and it has the following properties:

```
export interface ICaser {
    consulter: string;
    associater: string;
    typologies: string[];
    id:number;
}

const caser: ICaser = {
    consulter: "john",
    associater: "Huns",
    typologies: ['starter', 'beginner','intermediary','advanced']
};
```

And I am accessing the property by indexing, as follows:

```
_caser[fieldName as keyof ICaser] = value.key as string;
```

However, this works only for properties which are string type and not for property 'typologies' which is an array of strings.

My question is, how can I make it more generic that it can take any property, whether it is of type string, integer or array?

```
const handleOnFieldChange = (fieldName: string, value: IDropdownOption, index?: number | undefined) => {

        let _caser = Object.assign({}, caser);
        var vls;
        if (fieldName === "typologies") {
            vls = value.selected ?
                [..._caser.typologies!, value.key as string] : _caser.typologies.filter(key => key !== value?.key);
            _caser['typologies'] = vls;

        } else {
            _caser[fieldName as keyof ICaser] = value.key as string;
        }
        setCaser(_caser);
    }
```

using the example above, I will get the following which of course makes sense, but how do I solve it?

```
ype 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & string[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

Edit:
using it as follows: `_caser[fieldName]`, gives the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ICaser'.
```

Comment: Why not use only `_caser[fieldName]`?

Comment: because of this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ICaser'.

Comment: can you post the definition of `ICaser` type?

Comment: appologies, I thought I had posted it above. I have added above at the top of the post.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZ49Jw) meet your needs?  Note I needed to change things to make it a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  If it works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: the interface will contain different property types, like integers, strings, bool, and like IDropdown. I see you pointed this out in your code :  `//id: number; // <-- hey, this is a number, not s astring`

Comment: and I would like to remove the conditional here: `if (fieldName === "typologies")`, otherwise there will be a lot of IFs.